# select all records if join id is null

Tags: sql, select, null

Situation:

```
Table1: id, 
Table2: id, table1_id
Table3: id, table2_id
user: id, table1_id (can be null), table2_id(can be null), table3_id(can be null)
```

Table1, Table2, Table3 form hierarchical structure (for single table1 row thera are many rows in Table2, and for single Table2 row there are  many rows in Table3)

I need to select records from Table3 assigned for selected user.
Assigned means that id in user record match
 `(table1_id = Table1.id AND table2_id = Table2.id AND table3_id = Table3.id)`
However if value in user record is null it means that user is assigned for all records in corresponding table.

```
if table1_id = null query should return all rows
elif table2_id = null query should return all rows where (table1_id = Table1.id)
elif table3_id = null query should return all rows where (table1_id = Table1.id AND table2_id = Table2.id 
elif query should return all rows where (table1_id = Table1.id AND table2_id = Table2.id AND table3_id = Table3.id)
```

My proposition:

```
declare @table1_id int
declare @table2_id int
declare @table3_id int

select @table1_id = table1_id, @table2_id = @table2_id, @table3_id = @table3_id 
from user where id = 5 (5 is parmeter)

select * from Table3 where
(@table1_id IS NULL OR @table1_id = 
       (select table1_id from Table2 where Table2.id = Table3.table2_id)) AND
(@table2_id IS NULL OR @table2_id = Table3.table2_id) AND
(@table3_id IS NULL OR @table3_id = Table3.id)
```

Is that good sql query? Can I do better

Answer (score 1):

You can put this all into a single query:

```
select table3.*
from table3 cross join
     (select table1_id, table2_id, table3_id 
      from user
      where id = 5
     ) const
where (const.table1_id is null or const.table1_id in (select table1_id from table2 where table2.id = table3.table2_id)) and
      (const.table2_id is null or const.table2_id = table3.table2_id) and
      (const.table3_id is null or const.table3_id = table3.id)
```

I replaced the `=` with `in`, because you could have multiple returns from the subselect.

There are other ways to express this, using explicit joins.  However, they might result in duplicate rows, depending on the relationships between the tables.